# C# List field names in a JSonObject or JSonNode

Tags: c#, json

I need to process JSON arrays of varied precedence. The only thing they have in common is that the are array of JSON objects and that each object is a dictionary. Unfortunately, not all dictionary values are strings. Some are numbers, dates or boolean.

So my question is: Given a JSonObject or JsonNode how can list all it's fields so that I may then iterate over them and cast them as stirng.

It is importnat to remember that I don't know the fields name or type before hand. So I can't be defining classes for them.

My ideal output is a List < Dictionary<string,string> >

At this point I would put here what I have tried but unfortunatly I haven't found anything that does what I want.

I did try this:

```
 JsonArray list = node.AsArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++){
    
    JsonObject row = list[i].AsObject();
    string jstring = row.ToJsonString();
    Console.WriteLine(jstring);
    Dictionary<string,string> row_data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jstring);
    Console.WriteLine(row_data);

 }
```

Where node is the input to the function. But, as expected it did not work, as not all alues in the generated jstring contained " so when reinterpreting back to a dictionary it couldn't becuase they weren't strings.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample json showing the problem? A [mre] would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `Dictionary<string, string>` use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then convert all the values that now are represented as `object` to strings after deserializing.  Ideally you would know exactly what name/value types you can expect and define a type that represents that object but sometimes if you just don't know it's better to be flexible and use this type of dictionary.